# Zenfone 2 Deluxe custom rom - question about model variants

Tags: asus-zenfone-2

My phone went dead and a friend gave me his old Zenfone 2 Deluxe, which comes with the terrible ZenUI and a million asus apps that are a pain in the ass. I wanna throw it away and install a custom rom, something as clean as possible.

When googling, however, I find a lot of custom roms for Zenfone 2 laser, and for Zenfone 2 Z00A. According to Google, Zenfone 2 Deluxe is ZE551ML, however in the settings it says the model number is Z00AD. I'm very confused about this.

Of everything posted on [xda's zenfone 2 forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone2/development), it's very hard for me to understand which roms I can install and which I can't\shouldn't. Please advise, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZE551ML, Z00A, Z00AD and Z00AD* (A/B/C) refers to the same device, as evident on [ASUS' support page](https://www.asus.com/us/Phone/ZenFone_2_ZE551ML/HelpDesk_BIOS/):

[image]

The custom ROM community would refer to this device as Z00A. Look for ROMs targeting this codename.

On a side note, the "Laser" variants have Qualcomm SoCs (SD410/SD615), vastly different from the regular/Deluxe variants.